# How to update downloaded video status from "not yet watched" to "watched" in iOS settings app?

Tags: ios

I am working on an iOS app that allows user to download a video. I noticed that iOS automatically lists all downloaded videos in the settings app:
Settings -> General -> iPhone Storage ->  -> DOWNLOADED VIDEOS

Example:
[image]

All videos in downloaded section appear with state "not yet watched" even for already watched content.

Does anyone know a way to update the status from "not yet watched" to "watched"? Is there an any API function I use ?